# Dragging a List Items to Another List in MVC3

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I need 2 List.
First List contains List of Questions. (With QuestionID).
Second List is for Selected Questions.

Now When I Drag and Drop Question from Left List to Right side of List (Second List). It will be added in second list.

And When I click on Save i want to get All Selected Questions with its ID.

I need QuestionID which is not directly visible in List.List contains only Question Text.

I want to do it in Asp.net MVC3

Comment: So what are you having trouble with?

Comment: Did you identified the library to use for it? like http://jqueryui.com/sortable/

Comment: i want ti develop such UI.

Comment: i have tried one but i cannot get Question id Passed to another List.

Comment: Show us what you've tried. We'll help you with specific questions, but SO isn't a code writing service.

Comment: i have tried this http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#shopping-cart

Comment: All text should have one Unique ID and i want to Get ID and Text both from List when i click on save

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be drag & drop?

It sounds like you just need to multiselect questions.
Have a look at [this plugin](http://loudev.com/), it does pretty much what you described, except for the dragging and dropping. (which sounds more tedious, honestly)

Using, .Net MVC 3, you'll need to have something like this:

```
public class SomeModel
{
    public int[] SelectedQuestionIds { get; set; }
    public MultiSelectList AvailableQuestions { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your view:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedQuestionIds, Model.AvailableQuestions)
```

Then in your controller:

```
public ActionResult SaveQuestions(int[] selectedQuestionIds)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Yes finally i need Id in specific order.